# compare C++ STL list iterators

Tags: c++, list, stl

I have a C++ STL list of objects in my app that is built on startup and never altered afterwards; is it the case that two independent iterators that point to the same list node always compare equal ?

Answer (score 10):

Yes. One of the requirements for forward iterators is:

> C++11 22.4.5/6: If `a` and `b` are both dereferenceable, then `a == b` if and only if `*a` and `*b` are bound to the same object.

All iterators over standard containers are (at least) forward iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to cplusplus.com:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/ForwardIterator/

> Accepts equality/inequality comparisons.
>   Equal iterators imply the same element is pointed

(I'm not really a fan of this site but I'd trust it here.)

---

cppreference.com agrees and states more than that, namely all InputIterators (that can be read from) are EqualityComparable, see:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator